# how to stop 2 javax.swing.Timer

Tags: java, swing, timer

Im creating a reminder program in java, this program will call another 3 JFrame according user input
i success running 3 JFrame, but when i want to disable/ close the timer, only the first timer(SHORT BREAK) closed, the other two still run()

1.this is the code which handle each JFrame, as you can see i put 3 different method to call 3 different JFrame, but only the first method closed when i type timer.close();

```
private void callShortBreak(){  
    System.out.println("Start SHORT BREAK...");
    timer = new Timer(systemTime.getShortBreakTime(), new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            /*if(chckbxTakeAShort.isSelected()){*/
                /*Notification_Short_Break notif_short = new Notification_Short_Break();
                notif_short.runNotification();*/

                System.out.println("SHORT BREAK-"+loopShortBreak+" : "+ systemTime.getShortBreakTime() +" milisecond");
                loopShortBreak++;
            /*}  */         
        }
    });
    timer.setRepeats(true);
    timer.start();
}

private void callLongBreak(){   
    System.out.println("Start LONG BREAK...");  
    timer = new Timer(systemTime.getLongBreakTime(), new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            /*if(chckbxTakeALong.isSelected()){*/
                /*  Notification_Long_Break notif_long = new Notification_Long_Break();
                notif_long.runNotification(systemTime.getLongBreakDuration());*/

                System.out.println("LONG BREAK-"+loopLongBreak+" : "+ systemTime.getLongBreakTime() +" milisecond");
                loopLongBreak++;
            /*}   */        
        }
    });
    timer.setRepeats(true);
    timer.start();
}

private void callLongBreakNotify(){
    System.out.println("Start Notification LONG BREAK");

    timer = new Timer(systemTime.getLongBreakTime()-systemTime.getLongBreakNotifyTime(), new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            /*if(chckbxNotifiyLongBreak.isSelected()){*/
                /*Notification_Before_Long_Break notif_before_long = new Notification_Before_Long_Break();
                notif_before_long.runNotification();*/
                System.out.println("NOTIFICATION LONG BREAK-"+loopLongBreakNotification+" : "+ (systemTime.getLongBreakTime()-systemTime.getLongBreakNotifyTime()) +" milisecond");
                loopLongBreakNotification++;
            /*}*/
        }
    });
    timer.setRepeats(true);
    timer.start();
}
```

2.this is the code to call the code on above

```
public void timeSettings(){
        if(chckbxTakeALong.isSelected()){
            systemTime.setLongBreakTime(cbLongBreak.getSelectedIndex());
            systemTime.setLongBreakDuration(cbLongBreakDuration.getSelectedIndex());
            callLongBreak();
        } 
        if(chckbxNotifiyLongBreak.isSelected() &&  chckbxTakeALong.isSelected()){
            systemTime.setLongBreakNotifyTime(cbNotifyLongBreak.getSelectedIndex());
            callLongBreakNotify();
        }
        if(chckbxTakeAShort.isSelected()){
            systemTime.setShortBreakTime(cbShortBreak.getSelectedIndex());
            callShortBreak();   
        }
    }
```

3.this is the button which will close the timer

```
final JButton btnSaveAndClose = new JButton("Save and Close");
    btnSaveAndClose.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try{
                System.out.println("Stop all Timer.....");
                timer.stop();       
            }catch(Exception ex){

            }               
            settings_Page.timeSettings();
            saveCurrentSettings();
            settings_Page.dispose();
        }
    });
    btnSaveAndClose.setBounds(98, 331, 138, 23);
    getContentPane().add(btnSaveAndClose);
```

4.this is the complete Settings_Page class

```
    import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Composite;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.Timer;

import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowStateListener;

import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;

import com.eyecare.controller.Time;
import com.eyecare.controller.SystemPreferences;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.JMenuBar;

import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;


public class Settings_Page extends JFrame{

    private final String ENABLE_LONG_BREAK= "enableLongBreak";
    private final String NOTIFY_LONG_BREAK="notifyLongBreak";
    private final String ENABLE_SHORT_BREAK="enableShortBreak";
    public final String ENABLE_SOUND="enableSound";
    private final String ENABLE_STRICT_MODE="enableStrictMode";
    private final String HAVE_WINDOW_NEARBY="haveWindowNearby";

    private final String CB_LONG_BREAK = "cbLongBreak";
    private final String CB_LONG_BREAK_DURATION = "cbLongBreakDuration";
    private final String CB_NOTIFY_LONG_BREAK = "cbNotifyLongBreak";
    private final String CB_SHORT_BREAK="cbShortBreak";

    private final Boolean ENABLE_LONG_BREAK_VALUE = false;
    private final Boolean NOTIFY_LONG_BREAK_VALUE = false;
    private final Boolean ENABLE_SHORT_BREAK_VALUE = false;
    public final Boolean ENABLE_SOUND_VALUE = false;
    private final Boolean ENABLE_STRICT_MODE_VALUE = false;
    private final Boolean HAVE_WINDOW_NEARBY_VALUE = false;

    private final int CB_LONG_BREAK_VALUE = 0;
    private final int CB_LONG_BREAK_DURATION_VALUE = 0;
    private final int CB_NOTIFY_LONG_BREAK_VALUE = 0;
    private final int CB_SHORT_BREAK_VALUE =0;

    String[] comboBoxLongBreakContent = {"30 minutes","40 minutes","50 minutes","60 minutes","90 minutes","5 second","10 second"};
    String[] comboBoxTimeOffContent = {"2 minutes", "3 minutes","4 minutes","5 minutes","7 minutes","5 second"};
    String[] comboBoxNotifyContent = {"30 second","1 minutes","2 minutes","3 minutes","5 minutes","5 second"};
    String[] comboBoxShortBreakContent = {"3 minutes","5 minutes","8 minutes","10 minutes","15 minutes","5 second","10 second"};

    SystemPreferences sPreference = new SystemPreferences();
    static Settings_Page settings_Page = new Settings_Page();
    Timer timerShortBreak, timerLongBreak, timerNotifyLongBreak, timer;
    Time systemTime = new Time();
    TraySystem traySystem = new TraySystem();

    JCheckBox chckbxTakeALong, chckbxNotifiyLongBreak,chckbxTakeAShort,chckbxStrictMode,chckbxEnableSounds,chckbxIHaveA;
    JComboBox cbLongBreak, cbLongBreakDuration, cbNotifyLongBreak,cbShortBreak;

    int xMouse;
    int yMouse;
    private JLabel lblBackground;
    private JLabel lblDragJFrame;
    private JLabel lblNewLabel_2;
    private JLabel lblNewLabel_3;

    /*nanti di hapus yaa*/
    int loopShortBreak, loopLongBreak, loopLongBreakNotification;

    boolean isThisClassAlreadyRun =false;

    public Settings_Page() {
        setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(Settings_Page.class.getResource("/images/icons/Cika_ChibiIcon.png")));
        setResizable(false);
        setTitle("CiKare");
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        setUndecorated(true);


        /*JCheckBox starts here*/
        JLabel lblButtonExit = new JLabel("");
        lblButtonExit.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                settings_Page.dispose();
            }
        });
        lblButtonExit.setBounds(455, 6, 19, 19);
        lblButtonExit.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        getContentPane().add(lblButtonExit);

        JLabel lblButtonMinimize = new JLabel("");
        lblButtonMinimize.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                setState(Settings_Page.ICONIFIED);
            }
        });
        lblButtonMinimize.setBounds(425, 6, 19, 19);
        lblButtonMinimize.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        getContentPane().add(lblButtonMinimize);

        lblDragJFrame = new JLabel("");
        lblDragJFrame.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                xMouse = e.getX();
                yMouse = e.getY();
            }
        });
        lblDragJFrame.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                int x = e.getXOnScreen();
                int y = e.getYOnScreen();

                setLocation(x - xMouse, y - yMouse);
            }
        });
        lblDragJFrame.setBounds(0, 0, 481, 25);
        getContentPane().add(lblDragJFrame);


        chckbxTakeALong = new JCheckBox("Take a long break every");
        chckbxTakeALong.setOpaque(false);
        chckbxTakeALong.setBounds(44, 58, 161, 23);
        getContentPane().add(chckbxTakeALong);

        chckbxNotifiyLongBreak = new JCheckBox("Notifiy long break coming before ");
        chckbxNotifiyLongBreak.setOpaque(false);
        chckbxNotifiyLongBreak.setBounds(44, 95, 213, 23);
        getContentPane().add(chckbxNotifiyLongBreak);

        chckbxTakeAShort = new JCheckBox("Take a short break every");
        chckbxTakeAShort.setOpaque(false);
        chckbxTakeAShort.setBounds(44, 131, 171, 23);
        getContentPane().add(chckbxTakeAShort);

        chckbxStrictMode = new JCheckBox("Enable strict mode");
        chckbxStrictMode.setOpaque(false);
        chckbxStrictMode.setBounds(44, 204, 147, 23);
        getContentPane().add(chckbxStrictMode);

        chckbxEnableSounds = new JCheckBox("Enable sounds");
        chckbxEnableSounds.setOpaque(false);
        chckbxEnableSounds.setBounds(44, 168, 147, 23);
        getContentPane().add(chckbxEnableSounds);

        chckbxIHaveA = new JCheckBox("I have a window nearby");
        chckbxIHaveA.setOpaque(false);
        chckbxIHaveA.setBounds(44, 245, 161, 23);
        getContentPane().add(chckbxIHaveA);
        /*Jcheckbox ends here*/


        JLabel lblFor = new JLabel("for");
        lblFor.setBounds(321, 62, 20, 14);
        getContentPane().add(lblFor);

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("New label");
        lblNewLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Settings_Page.class.getResource("/images/icons/alarm.png")));
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(10, 51, 28, 36);
        getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);

        JLabel label = new JLabel("");
        label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Settings_Page.class.getResource("/images/icons/chat.png")));
        label.setBounds(9, 88, 28, 36);
        getContentPane().add(label);

        JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("New label");
        lblNewLabel_1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Settings_Page.class.getResource("/images/icons/alarm.png")));
        lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(10, 124, 28, 36);
        getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_1);

        JLabel label_1 = new JLabel("");
        label_1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Settings_Page.class.getResource("/images/icons/sound.png")));
        label_1.setBounds(10, 165, 28, 36);
        getContentPane().add(label_1);


        /*Jcombobox start here*/
        cbLongBreak = new JComboBox(comboBoxLongBreakContent);
        cbLongBreak.setBounds(211, 59, 96, 20);
        getContentPane().add(cbLongBreak);

        cbLongBreakDuration = new JComboBox(comboBoxTimeOffContent);
        cbLongBreakDuration.setBounds(351, 59, 96, 20);
        getContentPane().add(cbLongBreakDuration);

        cbNotifyLongBreak = new JComboBox(comboBoxNotifyContent);
        cbNotifyLongBreak.setBounds(274, 96, 96, 20);
        getContentPane().add(cbNotifyLongBreak);

        cbShortBreak = new JComboBox(comboBoxShortBreakContent);
        cbShortBreak.setBounds(221, 132, 96, 20);
        getContentPane().add(cbShortBreak);
        /*Jcombobox ends hre*/


        final JButton btnTryShortBreak = new JButton("Try short break");
        btnTryShortBreak.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Notification_Short_Break notif_short = new Notification_Short_Break();
                notif_short.runNotification();
            }
        });
        btnTryShortBreak.setBounds(10, 295, 138, 23);
        getContentPane().add(btnTryShortBreak);

        final JButton btnTryLongBreak = new JButton("Try long break");
        btnTryLongBreak.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Notification_Long_Break notif_long = new Notification_Long_Break();
                notif_long.runNotification();
            }
        });
        btnTryLongBreak.setBounds(169, 295, 138, 23);
        getContentPane().add(btnTryLongBreak);

        final JButton btnSaveAndClose = new JButton("Save and Close");
        btnSaveAndClose.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try{
                    System.out.println("Stop all Timer.....");
                    timer.stop();       
                }catch(Exception ex){

                }               
                settings_Page.timeSettings();
                saveCurrentSettings();
                settings_Page.dispose();
            }
        });
        btnSaveAndClose.setBounds(98, 331, 138, 23);
        getContentPane().add(btnSaveAndClose);

        lblNewLabel_2 = new JLabel("");
        lblNewLabel_2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Settings_Page.class.getResource("/images/icons/eye_close.png")));
        lblNewLabel_2.setBounds(6, 202, 38, 30);
        getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_2);

        lblNewLabel_3 = new JLabel("");
        lblNewLabel_3.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Settings_Page.class.getResource("/images/icons/window.png")));
        lblNewLabel_3.setBounds(9, 238, 38, 35);
        getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_3);

        lblBackground = new JLabel("");
        lblBackground.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Settings_Page.class.getResource("/images/icons/Background_settings_page.png")));
        lblBackground.setBounds(0, 0, 481, 389);
        getContentPane().add(lblBackground);

    }

    private void callShortBreak(){  
        System.out.println("Start SHORT BREAK...");
        timer = new Timer(systemTime.getShortBreakTime(), new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                /*if(chckbxTakeAShort.isSelected()){*/
                    /*Notification_Short_Break notif_short = new Notification_Short_Break();
                    notif_short.runNotification();*/

                    System.out.println("SHORT BREAK-"+loopShortBreak+" : "+ systemTime.getShortBreakTime() +" milisecond");
                    loopShortBreak++;
                /*}  */         
            }
        });
        timer.setRepeats(true);
        timer.start();
    }

    private void callLongBreak(){   
        System.out.println("Start LONG BREAK...");  
        timer = new Timer(systemTime.getLongBreakTime(), new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                /*if(chckbxTakeALong.isSelected()){*/
                    /*  Notification_Long_Break notif_long = new Notification_Long_Break();
                    notif_long.runNotification(systemTime.getLongBreakDuration());*/

                    System.out.println("LONG BREAK-"+loopLongBreak+" : "+ systemTime.getLongBreakTime() +" milisecond");
                    loopLongBreak++;
                /*}   */        
            }
        });
        timer.setRepeats(true);
        timer.start();
    }

    private void callLongBreakNotify(){
        System.out.println("Start Notification LONG BREAK");

        timer = new Timer(systemTime.getLongBreakTime()-systemTime.getLongBreakNotifyTime(), new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                /*if(chckbxNotifiyLongBreak.isSelected()){*/
                    /*Notification_Before_Long_Break notif_before_long = new Notification_Before_Long_Break();
                    notif_before_long.runNotification();*/
                    System.out.println("NOTIFICATION LONG BREAK-"+loopLongBreakNotification+" : "+ (systemTime.getLongBreakTime()-systemTime.getLongBreakNotifyTime()) +" milisecond");
                    loopLongBreakNotification++;
                /*}*/
            }
        });
        timer.setRepeats(true);
        timer.start();
    }

    public void timeSettings(){
        if(chckbxTakeALong.isSelected()){
            systemTime.setLongBreakTime(cbLongBreak.getSelectedIndex());
            systemTime.setLongBreakDuration(cbLongBreakDuration.getSelectedIndex());
            callLongBreak();
        } 
        if(chckbxNotifiyLongBreak.isSelected() &&  chckbxTakeALong.isSelected()){
            systemTime.setLongBreakNotifyTime(cbNotifyLongBreak.getSelectedIndex());
            callLongBreakNotify();
        }
        if(chckbxTakeAShort.isSelected()){
            systemTime.setShortBreakTime(cbShortBreak.getSelectedIndex());
            callShortBreak();   
        }
        if(chckbxEnableSounds.isSelected()){

        }
        if(chckbxStrictMode.isSelected()){

        }
        if(chckbxIHaveA.isSelected()){

        }
    }

    private void saveCurrentSettings(){
        sPreference.setBooleanSystemPreferences(ENABLE_LONG_BREAK, chckbxTakeALong.isSelected());
        sPreference.setBooleanSystemPreferences(NOTIFY_LONG_BREAK, chckbxNotifiyLongBreak.isSelected());
        sPreference.setBooleanSystemPreferences(ENABLE_SHORT_BREAK, chckbxTakeAShort.isSelected());
        sPreference.setBooleanSystemPreferences(ENABLE_STRICT_MODE, chckbxStrictMode.isSelected());
        sPreference.setBooleanSystemPreferences(ENABLE_SOUND, chckbxEnableSounds.isSelected());
        sPreference.setBooleanSystemPreferences(HAVE_WINDOW_NEARBY, chckbxIHaveA.isSelected());

        sPreference.setIntSystemPreferences(CB_LONG_BREAK, cbLongBreak.getSelectedIndex());
        sPreference.setIntSystemPreferences(CB_LONG_BREAK_DURATION, cbLongBreakDuration.getSelectedIndex());
        sPreference.setIntSystemPreferences(CB_NOTIFY_LONG_BREAK, cbNotifyLongBreak.getSelectedIndex());
        sPreference.setIntSystemPreferences(CB_SHORT_BREAK, cbShortBreak.getSelectedIndex());

        systemTime.setLongBreakTime(cbLongBreak.getSelectedIndex());
        systemTime.setLongBreakDuration(cbLongBreakDuration.getSelectedIndex());

        systemTime.setLongBreakNotifyTime(cbNotifyLongBreak.getSelectedIndex());

        systemTime.setShortBreakTime(cbShortBreak.getSelectedIndex());
    }

    private void loadCurrentSettings(){
        chckbxTakeALong.setSelected(sPreference.getBooleanSystemPreferences(ENABLE_LONG_BREAK, ENABLE_LONG_BREAK_VALUE));
        chckbxNotifiyLongBreak.setSelected(sPreference.getBooleanSystemPreferences(NOTIFY_LONG_BREAK, NOTIFY_LONG_BREAK_VALUE ));
        chckbxTakeAShort.setSelected(sPreference.getBooleanSystemPreferences(ENABLE_SHORT_BREAK, ENABLE_SHORT_BREAK_VALUE));
        chckbxStrictMode.setSelected(sPreference.getBooleanSystemPreferences(ENABLE_STRICT_MODE, ENABLE_STRICT_MODE_VALUE));
        chckbxEnableSounds.setSelected(sPreference.getBooleanSystemPreferences(ENABLE_SOUND, ENABLE_SOUND_VALUE));
        chckbxIHaveA.setSelected(sPreference.getBooleanSystemPreferences(HAVE_WINDOW_NEARBY, HAVE_WINDOW_NEARBY_VALUE));

        cbLongBreak.setSelectedIndex(sPreference.getIntSytemPreferences(CB_LONG_BREAK, CB_LONG_BREAK_VALUE));
        cbLongBreakDuration.setSelectedIndex(sPreference.getIntSytemPreferences(CB_LONG_BREAK_DURATION, CB_LONG_BREAK_DURATION_VALUE));
        cbNotifyLongBreak.setSelectedIndex(sPreference.getIntSytemPreferences(CB_NOTIFY_LONG_BREAK, CB_NOTIFY_LONG_BREAK_VALUE));
        cbShortBreak.setSelectedIndex(sPreference.getIntSytemPreferences(CB_SHORT_BREAK, CB_SHORT_BREAK_VALUE));
    }

/*if you want call from another activity use this*/
    public void runSettingsPage(){
        settings_Page.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.ICONIFIED);
        settings_Page.setSize(481,386);
        settings_Page.setVisible(true);
        settings_Page.loadCurrentSettings();
        if(isThisClassAlreadyRun!=true){
            settings_Page.timeSettings();
            isThisClassAlreadyRun=true;
        }   
    }


    public static void main(String [] args){
        settings_Page.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        settings_Page.setSize(481,386);
        settings_Page.setVisible(true);
        settings_Page.loadCurrentSettings();
        if(isThisClassAlreadyRun!=true){
            settings_Page.timeSettings();
            isThisClassAlreadyRun=true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need 3 fields for each timer (not just one timer)
So when you create second one the reference to the first is lost.

Define e.g.

```
Timer shortBreakTimer;
Timer longBreakTimer;
Timer anotherBreakTimer;
```

and on close stop all the 3 instances